# TStream as an object inside StringList

Tags: delphi, tstringlist, tstream

I am using Delphi 7 and playing with a StringList, with TStream as object.

My test project has a ListBox, a Memo and 2 buttons (Add and Remove).

Here is what I got so far:

```
var
  List: TStringList;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (List.Count > 0) then
    for I := 0 to Pred(List.Count) do
    begin
      List.Objects[I].Free;
      List.Objects[I] := nil;
    end;
  FreeAndNil(List);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strm: TStream;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo.Lines.SaveToStream(Strm);
    List.AddObject(IntToStr(List.Count), TObject(Strm));
    Memo.Clear;
    ListBox.Items.Assign(List);
  finally
//    Strm.Free; (line removed)
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDelFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (List.Count > 0) then
  begin
    List.Objects[0].Free;
    List.Objects[0] := nil;
    List.Delete(0);    
    ListBox.Items.Assign(List);
  end;
end;
```

When I double-click the ListBox I would like to load the selected item Stream object to Memo. Here is what I tried to do:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBoxDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Memo.Clear;
  Idx := ListBox.ItemIndex;
  if (Idx >= 0) and (TStream(List.Objects[Idx]).Size > 0) then
    Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(TStream(List.Objects[Idx]));
end;
```

My questions are:

1. Is correct the way I am adding and removing (freeing) the TStream object inside the StringList? Maybe I need to first free the Stream and then the Object??
2. Is correct the way I am freeing all objects on FormDestroy event?
3. When I try to load the stream back to Memo (Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(TStream(List.Objects[Idx]))), it doesn't load, despite Stream.Size is higher than zero. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need to cast `Strm` to `TObject` in the `List.AddObject(IntToStr(List.Count), TObject(Strm));` line `Strm` **IS** a TObject

Comment: @GerryColl, thank you for the tip!

Comment: Your mistake is to try to force a a stream into the Objects[] property. Create a type that holds what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Is correct the way I am adding and removing (freeing) the TStream object inside the StringList?

Yes, because the `TStrings.Objects[]` property returns a `TObject` pointer and `TStream` derives from `TObject`, so you can call `Free()` on the object pointers.

> Maybe I need to first free the Stream and then the Object??

You need to free the `TStream` objects before freeing the `TStringList` object. Just as you are already doing.

> 2.Is correct the way I am freeing all objects on FormDestroy event?

Yes. Though technically, you do not need to check the `TStringList.Count` property for `> 0` before entering the loop, as the loop will handle that condition for you.  And you do not need to `nil` the pointers before freeing the `TStringList`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Pred(List.Count) do
    List.Objects[I].Free;
  List.Free;
end;
```

One thing you are doing that is overkill, though, is `Assign()`ing the *entire* `TStringList` to the `TListBox` whenever you add/delete a single item from the `TStringList`.  You should instead simply add/delete the associated item from the ListBox and preserve the remaining items as-is.

And add some extra error checking to `btnAddClick()` as well to avoid any memory leaks if something goes wrong.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strm: TStream;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo.Lines.SaveToStream(Strm);
    Strm.Position := 0;
    Idx := List.AddObject(IntToStr(List.Count), Strm);
  except
    Strm.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  try
    ListBox.Items.Add(List.Strings[Idx]);
  except
    List.Objects[Idx].Free;
    List.Delete(Idx);
    raise;
  end;
  Memo.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDelFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if List.Count > 0 then
  begin
    List.Objects[0].Free;
    List.Delete(0);    
    ListBox.Items.Delete(0);
  end;
end;
```

> 3.When I try to load the stream back to Memo (Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(TStream(List.Objects[Idx]))), it doesn't load, despite Stream.Size is higher than zero. What I am doing wrong?

You are not seeking the stream back to `Position` 0 before loading it into the Memo.  `SaveToStream()` always leaves the stream positioned at the end of the stream, and `LoadFromStream()` leave the stream positioned wherever the load stopped reading from (if not at the end, in case of failure).

Now, with all of this said, I personally would not use `TListBox` in this manner. I would instead set its `Style` property to `lbVirtual` and then use its `OnData` event to display the strings from the `TStringList`.  No need to copy them into the `TListBox` directly, or try to keep the two lists in sync at all times.  It would be safer, and use less memory, to let the `TListBox` ask you for what it needs, and then you can provide it from the `TStringList` (which I would then change to a `TList` since you are not really storing meaningful names that can't be produced dynamically in the `OnData` event handler):

```
var
  List: TList;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  List := TList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ListBox.Count := 0;
  for I := 0 to Pred(List.Count) do
    TStream(List[I]).Free;
  List.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strm: TStream;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo.Lines.SaveToStream(Strm);
    Strm.Position := 0;
    Idx := List.Add(Strm);
  except
    Strm.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  try
    ListBox.Count := List.Count;
  except
    TStream(List[Idx]).Free;
    List.Delete(Idx);
    raise;
  end;
  Memo.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDelFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if List.Count > 0 then
  begin
    TStream(List[0]).Free;
    List.Delete(0);    
    ListBox.Count := List.Count;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Strm: TStream;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Memo.Clear;
  Idx := ListBox.ItemIndex;
  if Idx >= 0 then
  begin
    Strm := TStream(List[Idx]);
    if Strm.Size > 0 then
    begin
      Strm.Position := 0;
      Memo.Lines.LoadFromStream(Strm);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var Data: string);
begin
  Data := IntToStr(Index);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't understand what you suggest about freeing the stream and then the object. As I understand it, the object you're talking about freeing *is* the stream. You can't destroy one before the other because there's only one object, which is a stream.
2. Your methods of adding and removing stream objects in the string list are fine. They're not ideal, but I'll limit my comments here because Stack Overflow isn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).
3. After you call `SaveToStream`, the stream's position is at the *end* of the stream. If you want to read from the stream, then you'll have to set the position back to the start again. Set `Position := 0` for the stream prior to calling `LoadFromStream`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `Assign()`ing the `TStringList` to the `TListBox` will also assign the `TStream` objects to the ListBox as associated user-defined values of the list items (via the `LB_SETITEMDATA` message).

Comment: @RobKennedy, about the first question I thought that maybe I need first to free the Stream (TStream(List.Objects[Idx]).Free) and then the object itself. But now I understood... About second question, give me a tip about the ideal method for this, please :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the tip. I assigned the stringlist to listbox only for testing. The purpose of this code is to use with TIdThreadSafeStringList, in the IdTCPServer communication, so it can know when send a stream to client.

Comment: @Paruba: This is not a good way to manage client communications with `TIdTCPServer`.

Comment: I'll give you all the tips you want on Code Review, which is the place for asking open-ended questions about how to improve working code.

Comment: @RobKennedy, ok, thank you! I will use Code Review next time.